# Python .strip() function gives error on variable with HTML (BeautifulSoup)

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

This code scrapes amazon for a product name. I wanted to strip this variable, which contains HTML of its whitespace,

```
span = soup.find("span", id="productTitle")
print(span.strip())
```

but it gives me this error;

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/avensis/Desktop/Projects/AmazonScraper/Scraper.py", line 17, in <module>
    print(span.strip())
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

I don't understand why this occurs. Can someone please explain? Here is my full code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import html5lib

url = 'https://www.amazon.co.uk/Pingu-PING2573-Mug/dp/B0764468MD/ref=sr_1_11?dchild=1&keywords=pingu&qid=1595849018' \
      '&sr=8-11 '
headers = {
    "User-Agent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
                  'Chrome/84.0.4147.89 Safari/537.36'}
page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html5lib')
span = soup.find("span", id="productTitle")
print(span.strip())
```

Comment: span is `None` because beautiful soup didn't find a `span` of `id="productTitle"`. This is what's giving you the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is what you want to do:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import html5lib
import random

url = 'https://www.amazon.co.uk/Pingu-PING2573-Mug/dp/B0764468MD/ref=sr_1_11?dchild=1&keywords=pingu&qid=1595849018' \
      '&sr=8-11 '
headers = {
    "User-Agent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
                  'Chrome/84.0.4147.89 Safari/537.36'}
page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html5lib')


span = soup.find("span", id="productTitle")

print(span.get_text(strip=True))
```

prints:

```
Pingu - Mug | 300 ml | Ceramic | Gift Box | 11 x 8.5 x 8.5 cm
```

If it is what you looking for it was the `.get_text(strip=True)` you missed

Comment: Clear and exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Use `.get_text()` method:

```
span.get_text().replace("\n", "")

'Pingu - Mug | 300 ml | Ceramic | Gift Box | 11 x 8.5 x 8.5 cm'
```